# Failed to restart Hadoop namenode using cloudera quickstart

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I use Windows 8 with a cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2-0 virtual box. I am wanting to put a "words.txt" file in the HDFS. I got a connection exception.

I checked other StackOverflow threads/solutions and tried the following:

- I checked the status of the `namenode` and datanode.
  It seems that the `namenode` is dead while the datanode is running.
- I restarted the `namenode`, but it is still not running.

Here is a screenshot of the terminal using showing all the steps:
[terminal.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggTyp.png)

I have no clue what to do next in order to solve the problem I have.

Note: I am new to Hadoop, so I am not familiar with most of the technical terms associated with it. A descriptive solution is very much appreciated.

Comment: check namenode's log, any error/exception?

Comment: I am completely new to Hadoop, so I unfortunately don't know now to check the log of the namenode. Could you help me with that? I am very curious to check out the log.

Comment: Any reason you're not using Cloudera Manager to restart your NameNode?
 And BTW, your log file is listed in your screenshot:  /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-quickstart.cloudera.out

Comment: Use Hue to upload files in CDH Quickstart

Comment: I fixed my problem using this link: 
http://kshitish-bigdata.blogspot.nl/2015/02/hadoop-namenode-is-dead-and-pid-file.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my own problem

Check status of all services:
`for  service in /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-*; do $service status; done;` , output should be:

```
Hadoop datanode is running [  OK  ]  
Hadoop namenode is dead and pid file exists [FAILED]  
Hadoop secondarynamenode is running  [  OK  ]
```

To get the namenode running do the following:

- stop all services: `for  service in /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-*; do $service stop; done;`
- clear cache from cache directory: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/*`
- reformat name node: `sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode -format`
- start all services: `for  service in /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-*; do $service start; done;`
- check status: `for  service in /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-*; do $service status; done;`

Result should be:

```
Hadoop datanode is running [  OK  ]  
Hadoop namenode is running [  OK  ]  
Hadoop secondarynamenode is running [  OK  ]
```

As described in the following link:

http://kshitish-bigdata.blogspot.nl/2015/02/hadoop-namenode-is-dead-and-pid-file.html